# Group by major count

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Greetings I have a question having sql like

```
select top 100 tab.user as username,
case tab.event 
    when 1 then 'Add'
    when 2 then 'Remove'
    when 3 then 'Update'
end as event,
count(tab.countOfEvents) as count_events
from history tab 
where tab.even is not null and tab.date <= DATEADD(day, 1, getdate())
group by tab.event, tab.user
order by count_events desc
```

Im getting result like:

```
user  event  count_event
  a   Update    100
  b   Update    89
  a   Add       19
  c   Remove    18
  b   Add       10
  a   Remove    9
```

Now is is possible that i can get result sorted by highes user activity (sum of activieties), but still sorted by user (I need event name) for example:

```
user  event  count_event
  a   Update    100
  a   Add       19
  a   Remove    9
  b   Update    89
  b   Add       10
  c   Remove    18

  etc ...
```

Comment: order by user, count_events desc

Comment: Are you searching for `order by user asc, count_events desc`?

Comment: I can't see user activity field anywhere :(

Comment: Tried ordering by user and events, its allays ordering users by alphabet not by events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have ordered only on count_events field.

If you want to change order criteria, change this:

```
order by count_events desc
```

to

```
order by tab.user, count_events desc
```

in this way you'll order at first by user and then by count_events.